# DDD: Two entities with different cardinality - depending on the "context"

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a configuration plane: A Task has 1..n Sub-Tasks there (Sub-Tasks cannot be reused by other Tasks – so each Task has its own Sub-Tasks)

At runtime, if a user creates a task (by instating a task from the configuration plane – so the id is the same because its unique in the parent entity – so the parent entity can only have 1 task with id X where X is the id of the configuration plane task), he must select 1 sub-task.

How do I model this in DDD? I created now 2 contexts:

- Configuration-plane-context: Task 1..n Sub-Task
- Runtime-context: Task 1..1 Sub-Task

But actually, the entities are equal – I have now duplicate entities.

Comment: It looks like you need to create association table instead of sub-tasks table. You can just create associations between configurable plane tasks and runtime tasks.

Comment: But I talk about the DDD and not about tables :-) So - Domain-Model, Design-Model but not the physical model

Comment: Part of the point of bounded contexts is that it's totally acceptable for those to each have their own language, even if that means terms mean different things (in this case, in the context of the configuration plane, tasks have potentially multiple subtasks, but in the runtime, it's 1:1).  At the boundary, you have read models or anti-corruption layers to translate between them.  Note that this implies that a runtime task and a configuration task are, in fact, different (so no duplication).